Is it possible to copy Azure SQL databases to SQL Server?

The production databases are running on Azure SQL;
The staging databases are running on SQL Server inside of a Kubernetes cluster on AKS, using a Spot node pool.

Now, I need a new environment and this new environment's databases need to be recreated daily on top of a recent snapshot of production.
As there are multiple databases, I guess that Azure SQL would be expensive, so I would like to use SQL Server as I already do with the staging environments.
What I've done so far:

Use Azure Automation runbooks (running daily) to export the databases from Azure SQL into Azure Blob Storage as BACPAC files;
Configured the credentials for the Azure Blob Storage via Shared Access Signature on SQL Server (and the credentials are working, as I tested and was able to backup a SQL Server database into Blob Storage, but that's not what I want);
But, when I run RESTORE DATABASE [test1] FROM URL = 'https://<myblobaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/database_latest.bacpac', it fails with:


The media family on device
'https://.blob.core.windows.net//database_latest.bacpac'
is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.

It seems that importing BACPAC exported by Azure SQL into SQL Server isn't possible.

You don't use the RESTORE DATABASE command with bacpacs. Use SqlPackage.exe

Thanks. Do you know if I can point to a BACPAC in a Blob Storage when using SqlPackage?

Yes, @deniable_encryption . You might want to have a read of the documentation

I guess that Azure SQL would be expensive maybe validate that first. Elastic pools and pausable instances are made to reduce costs in Azure SQL.


The media family on device 'https://.blob.core.windows.net//database_latest.bacpac' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.

The cause of this error is Restore Data base process the .bak file and you are providing .bacpac file to it.
The solution can be as suggested by @Martin Smith to use SqlPackage.exe utility package but for that first you need to download the .bacpac file from blob storage for that you can use below command in cmd/powershell:
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://storage_acc_name.blob.core.windows.net/storage_cont_name/WideWorldImporters-Standard.bacpac -OutFile "C:\destination_path\WideWorldImporters-Standard.bacpac"


After file downloaded you can export it using SqlPackage.exe utility
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin>sqlpackage.exe /Action:Import /tsn:MSSQLSERVER01 /tdn:Importdb1 /tu:user /tp:password /sf:"C:\destination_path\WideWorldImporters-Standard.bacpac"


